# How to show posts of friendly user with a logged in person

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have three tables - User and Friend($owner, $friend) that have the ManyToMany relations and Post - connected to User OneToMany. Friend table was created by @JoinTable, and my problem is to create a proper query that will show posts of friendly user with a logged in person;

PostRepository:

```
/**
 * @param User $user
 * @return array
 */
public function selectFriendsPost(User $user)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder("post")
        ->select('user', 'friends', 'owners')
        ->leftJoin('user.friends', 'friends')
        ->leftJoin('user.owners', 'owners')
        ->where('post.owner = : friends')
        ->setParameter('userId', $user->getFriends())
        ->orderBy("post.createdAt", "DESC")
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

User Entity:

```
/**
 * @var Post[]ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="owner")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $posts;
  /**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="owners")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Friend",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="friend_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $friends;

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="friends")
 */
private $owners;
```

error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 84 near '.friends friends': Error: Identification Variable user used in join path expression but was not defined before.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
->leftJoin('BundleName:User','user','WITH','user.pkUser= post.refUser')
```

Try to join table in this way..first `BundleName:EntityName` then alias `name` then `with` then joining statement .